# Is the following request-scoped injection thread-safe?

Tags: servlets, cdi

```
@WebListener
public class AllRequestsWebListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Inject HttpRequestProducer producer;

    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
    producer.requestInitialized(sre);
    }
}
```

...

```
@RequestScoped
public class HttpRequestProducer {
...
}
```

I don't know howto inject request-bean as method-parameter and therefore I can guess that it will work properly when Request-bean injection is threadLocal. Can someone explain me how it's implemented in a thread-safe manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intuition based answer**

I believe it is thread safe, as request scope is thread safe (session and above are not, as a user can open multiple browser sessions and use the same session ID)

I tested it, although it's empiric evidence, but the injected `HttpRequestProducer` gets a new instance each request.

Note that the `requestInitialized` and `requestDestroyed` can be (and in practice are) different threads, so I will investigate further if you intend to use the same injected object on both methods.

**Specs backed answer**

The hard part was to find hard evidence for this claim in the specs.

I looked into the CDI spec and couldn't quickly find conclusive evidence that a @RequestScoped object is thread safe (e.g. using thread local) however I assume that a @RequestScoped bean is using the same scope as the scoped beans in Java EE 5: (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html#bnafs))

In there this clause is interesting:

> Controlling Concurrent Access to Shared Resources In a multithreaded
>   server, it is possible for shared resources to be accessed
>   concurrently. In addition to scope object attributes, shared resources
>   include in-memory data (such as instance or class variables) and
>   external objects such as files, database connections, and network
>   connections.
>
> Concurrent access can arise in several situations:
>
> - Multiple web components accessing objects stored in the web context.
> - Multiple web components accessing objects stored in a session.
> - Multiple threads within a web component accessing instance variables.
>     A web container will typically create a thread to handle each request.
>     If you want to ensure that a servlet instance handles only one request
>     at a time, a servlet can implement the SingleThreadModel interface. If
>     a servlet implements this interface, you are guaranteed that no two
>     threads will execute concurrently in the servlet’s service method. A
>     web container can implement this guarantee by synchronizing access to
>     a single instance of the servlet, or by maintaining a pool of web
>     component instances and dispatching each new request to a free
>     instance. This interface does not prevent synchronization problems
>     that result from web components accessing shared resources such as
>     static class variables or external objects. In addition, the Servlet
>     2.4 specification deprecates the SingleThreadModel interface.

So in theory, it seems that the object itself is going to have one instance per request thread, however I couldn't find any hard evidence that this is supported.

Answer (score 1):

What you have injected in your bean is a proxy representing the real deal. The proxy will always forward the invocation to the correct bean